# Unicode message inserting in different way - php

Tags: php, mysql, unicode, unicode-string

I'm trying to insert a Unicode message in my database.

`+9195******** पर मुझे फोन`

Its inserting like the below line.

`+9195******** à¤ªà¤° à¤®à¥à¤à¥‡ à¤«à¥‹à¤¨`

Can anybody tell me how to overcome this issue ?

Comment: Do you have problem rendering in your HTML or dont like the database selected collation?

Comment: I mentioned meta utf tag in html, In database only its inserting like that.

Comment: what is table collation ... it suppose to be utf8_general_ci

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to change the table collation to UTF8

```
alter table *table_name* CONVERT TO CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider if this is the query,

```
  $test = "...SQL Query...";
  $result = mysql_query($test);
```

Just add this alone in above of `$test`

```
 $result = mysql_query("SET NAMES utf8");
```

Your final code should be,

```
 $result = mysql_query("SET NAMES utf8");
 $test = "...SQL Query...";
 $result = mysql_query($test);
```

Also, add this line at the top,

```
 header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
```